# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process {your_package_name}

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have Followed the Proper Step's.

I did Restart my IDE and Cleaned and Rebuild

Anyone Know of any other Solutions?

[image]

```
    "storage_bucket": "######.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:#####:android:########",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.lionmarketing.ecombetaz"
        }
      },
```

[image]